# Javascript Twice enter in textarea not detected by (/[\n\r]/gm)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I uploaded my work at github , you guys can check the code there > https://adminphdcommy.github.io/cr-checker/

The JS trigger by keydown and will create.

I categorize the result by paragraph (new line), JS will remove newline from array by using Regexp (/[\n\r]/gm).

However, when i spam more than 2 empty newline then only continue typing, it is not detected by the regexp.

Example of textarea input:

```
PO PO PO PO
<--This part detected as newline-->
PO
<--This part detected as newline-->
<--This part unable to detect as newline-->
PO
```

### Result in Console.log:

["po po po po", "po", "", "po"]

---

My Code to get textarea value and create array:

```
var crinput = document.getElementById("textarea1").value
var paracountarray = crinput.split(/[\n\r]/gm);
```

My code to remove empty string in array:

```
for(a=0;a<paracountarray.length;a++){
        if(paracountarray[a] == ""){
            paracountarray.splice(a,1)
        }
    }
```

Please advise how to remove the "" in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example, I'm not sure I'm grasping what you want.  When running your code in the console, it "works for me" giving me what I would expect: an extra empty array element:

```
>> var testStr = 'PO PO PO PO\n\nPO\n\n\nPO'
>> testStr.split(/[\n\r]/gm)
Array [ "PO PO PO PO", "", "PO", "", "", "PO" ]
```

Perhaps you'd like a different result?  Consider a "once or more times" match:

```
var paracountarray = crinput.split(/[\n\r]+/gm);
```

That will count fifteen consecutive newlines as a single paragraph break.  So in your example, this would give you three paragraphs.  With the previous example:

```
>> var testStr = 'PO PO PO PO\n\nPO\n\n\nPO'
>> testStr.split(/[\n\r]+/gm)
Array [ "PO PO PO PO", "PO", "PO" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for one or more new line jumps at once with your regexp(/[\r\n]+/gm `/[\r\n]+/gm`.

```js
function paracount(){
  var crinput = document.getElementById("textarea1").value
  var paracountarray = crinput.split(/[\r\n]+/gm);
  console.log(paracountarray);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" onchange="paracount()"></textarea>
```